# Insert new key value into nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to insert a new key/value `{ type: 'Profile'}` into the photo hash that has id = 111.

```
photo_hash = [{"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"}, {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
```

So the final result should look like:

```
photo_hash = [{"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg", "type" : "Profile"}, {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
```

I feel like this should be pretty straight forward in Ruby but I am very stuck

Comment: This isn't really a nested hash. It's an array of hashes.

Comment: `("type" : "Profile")` isn't valid Ruby syntax.

Comment: BTW, the quotes around the hash keys are superfluous and pretty misleading – it makes the keys look like strings. But `"id":` is in fact just `id:`, i.e. a symbol.

Comment: If you want String keys you need to do `"id" => "111"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a new array from your existing:

```
photos = [{"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"}, {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]

new_photos = photos.map do |photo|
  if photo[:id] == '111'
    photo.merge(type: 'Profile')
  else
    photo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The question suggests to me that the element `h` (a hash) of `photos` for which `h[:id] = "111` (if there is one), is to be modified in place by adding the key-value pair `:type=>"Profile"`.

```
photos = [{"id": "111", "photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"},
          {"id": "222", "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]

insert_item = { "type": "Profile" }
```

```
h = photos.find { |h| h[:id] == "111" }
h.update(insert_item) unless h.nil?
photos
  #=> [{:id=>"111", :photo=>"http://photo.com/111.jpeg", :type=>"Profile"},
  #    {:id=>"222", :photo=>"http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
```

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`).

Comment: You can also use the alternative syntax `h = photos.find { |h| h[:id] == "111" } and h.update(insert_item)` which does the same in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You rly dont need to find object or create new `Array`.
`Hash` it self its object and can be updated.

```
photos = [{"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"}, {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
photos.each do |hsh|
  if hsh[:id] == '111'
    hsh[:type] = 'Profile'
    break
  end
end
photos
# => [{:id=>"111", :photo=>"http://photo.com/111.jpeg", :type=>"Profile"}, {:id=>"222", :photo=>"http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update multiple values from different objects with different ids you could also build a lookup tree. (Assuming there are no duplicate ids.)

```
photos = [{"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"}, {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}]
photo_lookup = photos.map { |photo| [photo[:id], photo] }.to_h
#=> { 
#   "111" => {"id": "111","photo": "http://photo.com/111.jpeg"},
#   "222" => {"id": "222",  "photo": "http://photo.com/222.jpeg"}
# }
```

Then simply fetch the photo and update the value.

```
photo = photo_lookup["111"] and photo.update(type: 'Profile')
#                            ^ only update photo if it is found
```

This solution mutates the hash, meaning the hash in `photos` should also be updated.